# wampserver or php（5.5.12）can't recognize codeigniter ？

Tags: php, codeigniter, wampserver

I can enter in localhost by wampserver， but when I want to enter in other webs by my localhost ，the problem comes,just look like my picture

[image: img1]

I use the  codeigniter frame.i think my php can't recognize  that frame or not?

because  i can get in some webs by localhost,when the  URL order is same as the web's URl order(don't use codeigniter frame)  .

[image: img2]
so that if web use the codeigniter frame , i will fail .
If web don't use the codeigniter frame ,i can succeed to get in the web?
 So how can i solve it?

Comment: did you add htaccess file in inside the feeback folder?

Comment: did you create a folder in wamp > www > feedback and then put codeigniter in there? but as @Gopalakrishnan about the htaccess

Comment: yes wamp > www > feedback >(codeigniter framework) htaccess @wolfgang

Comment: under《 www》 I have no《 feedback》 folder .

Comment: but i have all the feedback elements  in others folder  that's in the《www》

Comment: try auto loading the URL helper `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Then you did the install incorrectly

Comment: You should create a Virtual Host to run something like codeigniter properly see this post for how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618 then remove this install and do the install again into `http://whatever_servname_you_created_as_a_virtualhost`

Comment: This has nothing to do with virtualhosting a website, it's very likely to be your htaccess that isnt set correctly, could you post your htaccess ? Can you also try to put localhost/feedback/index.php and see if that works?

Comment: Make sure to set the correct path in your browser, if your CI installation isnt located at WWW > feedback then ur URL won't be localhost/feedback. Please show us where you have the CI installed from your root WWW directory.